# Wordress admin url change www to admin

Tags: wordpress

I am wondering if it is possible. right now; Wordpress allows me to access the admin panel with www and without www.

is it possible I am able to access admin panel by admin.domain.com instead of www.domain.com

because www and admin both are subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

While it's technically possible to do this, it requires some changes in your wp-config file and server configuration.

If you want `https://admin.example.com` to display the admin panel? → that's even more complex but I think it could be done with some htaccess rules.

It will be simpler if you want to have `https://admin.example.com/wp-admin` as the admin panel and `https://www.example.com` as front-end.

I do not recommend that change though, as it would limit some WordPress features (such as front-end editing), it will cause lots of problems when you want to allow your users to log in (e.g., to post a comment or access their WooCommerce account)

→ The main problem is, that `admin.example.com` and `www.example.com` cannot share cookies and are treated as independent websites by your browser. You would need to log in twice - once in `admin.example.com` and once in `www.example.com` - to access the admin panel and unlock the comment form (for example).

**TL;DR**

I do not recommend doing this unless you know exactly what you do (and have really good reasons to do this).